# Join two SQL queries where the second only returns one row and column

Tags: sql, join

I have a query which returns a list of jobs in the following format:

```
JobName    Weight
-----------------
3484       2958
7843       6833
0065       6768
```

I also have another select query (looking at another table) which always returns the name of the current job being run.

```
Current_Job
-----------
0065
```

How can I combine these two queries to produce the following?

```
JobName    Weight      Current_Job
----------------------------------
3484       2958        0065
7843       6833        0065
0065       6768        0065
```

Thanks

Comment: can you explain a bit more? with table and column names and foreign keys. I guess it will be select JobName, Weight, Current_Job from table1, table2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT JobName, Weight, Current_Job
FROM (yourfirstquery) q1, (yoursecondquery) q2
```

Comment: FYI this is long deprecated syntax.

Comment: @MattWhitfield: I never use this syntax but it's not deprecated. Outdated yes. Deprecated no. (backwards compatibility is a killer in SQL, isn't it?)

Comment: @MattWhitfield We don't know that the OP isn't using some archaic SQL database :)

Comment: @ypercube - Sorry I was talking from the SQL Server world. And I was wrong anyway, it's specifically the `*=` and `=*` that are deprecated. My apologies.

Comment: @podiluska - No, but we can hope :)

Comment: @MattWhitfield I guess you mean the `*=` and `=*`

Answer (score 4):

That would be

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Table1 CROSS JOIN 
       Table2
```